Counterexample for a characterization of flatness
Proposition 3.60 in the book: An introduction to homological algebra by Rotman says:
Proposition 3.60 Let $0 \rightarrow K \rightarrow F \rightarrow A \rightarrow 0$ be an exact sequence of right $R$-modules in which $F$ is flat. Then $A$ is a flat module if and only if $K \cap FI = KI$ for every finitely generated left ideal $I$.
I'm trying to come up with a counterexample to see the proposition would fails in the case of infinitely generated left ideal $I$, but have not found anything yet. It seems to me that the proposition would also be true if we remove the hypothesis of finitely generated ideal.
Any help would be appreciated!!
Thanks.

You are correct that the statement is still true if you remove "finitely generated".
But note that this doesn't give a stronger theorem.
It does give a stronger version of the "only if" direction, as flatness implies something about all ideals, and not just finitely generated ideals as in the original statement.
However, it gives a weaker version of the "if" direction. The version without "finitely generated" would say that you had to check a condition for all ideals in order to prove that $A$ is flat, but with the original version you only have to check finitely generated ideals.

Hi @Jeremy Rickard, thanks for your answer!! In the proof the author uses the fact that finitely generated ideal preserves exactness when applying tensor product to it. Without "finitely generated", it certainly failed!! So I'm curious about the proof of the theorem without the hypothesis of finitely generated. Do you have any resources on proving the theorem without using finitely generated?

@the-only-cat-loving-philosophy I'm afraid I don't see where you think Rotman's proof uses "finitely generated". Until the very last sentence, it doen't even mention whether the ideals that it considers are finitely generated. And that last sentence is to prove that if $K\cap FI=KI$ for every finitely generated ideal $I$, then $A$ is flat. And of course if that statement is true with the words "finitely generated" included, then a fortiori it's true without them.

Hi @Jeremy Rickard. At the begining Rotman says For every left ideal $I$, right exactness of $\square \otimes_R I$....and this happens only when $I$ is finitely generated, please correct if I'm wrong here

@the-only-cat-loving-philosophy Tensoring with any module is right exact.
